# How to create icon view to list view and vice versa switching mechanism in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking to create an application where some items are showcased. Currently they are being shown in a list with title, subtitle, icon and some information. I am thinking of implementing a layout switcher here, which will enable to user to change this view to lets say icon view where they may be displayed as a grid of 3 columns. Also this switching can be animated if possible. There will be two buttons over the view, one representing list view and other icon. Clicking on any will show up the respective view. Any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 1):

for list

`gridview.setNumColumns(1);`

and for grid

`gridview.setNumColumns(2);`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bolster, ...and where is the actual link?

Comment: Grr... It's autocommented from the review side. It's a 'answer with no explanation' issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the view shown in activity using setContentView() method you can call setcontentview in onClick callback.so that whole you can switch between gridview and listview.
Cheers....